# Do patients with angina have a high risk of dying?

Tags: heart-disease, angina

Angina is a common form of heart disease. Is it a highly dangerous condition with high risk of death in short term? What is one year death rate in patients diagnosed with angina?

Answer (score 2):

Giving a definitive answer is not easy because angina is often not the only condition patients with angina suffer from. Thus, it can't be looked at "in a vacuum", so to speak. And, of course, it also very much depends on whether adequate medical care is available.

Numbers also vary between the forms of angina: stable angina and unstable angina. Stable angina might develop into unstable angina, which can be one of the first signs of a heart attack ([What is angina?](http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/health-topics/topics/angina))

**Stable angina**

> Long-term prognosis for those with stable angina is variable, with mortality rates of between 0.9%– 6.5% per annum

[The management of stable angina](http://bjcardio.co.uk/2011/10/the-management-of-stable-angina/)

Since patients with angina are often older and already in bad health, these numbers *might* even be the same or close to the "normal" death rate. As you can see from the wide range, the risk varies a lot.

The introduction section of [Favourable long term prognosis in stable angina pectoris: an extended follow up of the angina prognosis study in Stockholm (APSIS)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1860751/) lists a lot of studies that found an annual death risk of about one percent, often not different from control groups without angina. This is the rate for patients with good state-of-the-art medical care and treatment, though.

**Unstable angina**

Unstable angina is a condition that [needs to be treated with emergency medical care](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/HeartAttack/SymptomsDiagnosisofHeartAttack/Unstable-Angina_UCM_437513_Article.jsp#mainContent), as it is one of the signs of a heart attack. If the patient survives the first months, the death risk returns to the level of stable angina.

> This observational study reported that the in-hospital event rates for unstable angina included a 2% mortality rate, 4% progression to myocardial infarction and 3% recurrence of refractory ischaemia. **By 6 months this had risen to 7% mortality**, 7% myocardial infarction and 17% recurrent myocardial ischaemia. One year after the index episode of unstable angina, the cardiovascular event rate had returned to that of patients with stable angina and a similar risk factor profile.

[Unstable angina: the first 48 hours and later in-hospital management](http://m.bmb.oxfordjournals.org/content/59/1/69.full)

Comment: Please tell me if this doesn't answer your question - I searched for untreated rates, but that's kind of hard to come by, as ethically, doctors can't just let patients with angina go untreated and haven't done so for decades.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. From where have you quoted mortality rates of "0.9%– 6.5% per annum" ? I could not find it in http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/health-topics/topics/angina .

Comment: @rncardio the source for that quote is "The management of stable angina" below it : http://bjcardio.co.uk/2011/10/the-management-of-stable-angina/